# How to store an input string and use it to save a file...?

Tags: matlab

How can I use the variable name from an input with the sprintf function and write it as part of the filename.

```
   allData = input('Introduce a variable name:','s');

   matfilename = sprintf('xcross_%d_.mat',names(k));
```

i.e:  During the input process I enter the variable name Hands_X

So I want to added into the filename as this:

> ```
> xcross_0914_Hands_X.mat
> ```

Thank you so much advance!!!!

Comment: I'm a little confused. What do you enter at the prompt? What you enter is simply saved to `allData` as a string.

Comment: Your code does not really make sense as far as I can see. Please provide a minimal example of what you want to achieve and remove the unnecessary clutter from the code. Therefore please edit your question accordingly. In case you just want to use a string in `sprintf`: add `%s` in the format string (first argument) and add the variable containing the actual string as another argument.

Comment: Sorry, it was a mess.... 

I've tried introducing the %s but still I don't know how can I add the variable containing the string to an another argument. 

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mentioned in the comment that you *don't know how to add the variable containing the string as another argument*, I'm going to explain the principle of using `sprintf`.

Let's have a look at the documentation accessible by `doc sprintf` in the command window or in the online documentation [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html):

> str = sprintf(formatSpec,A1,...,An)

We see that `sprintf` takes a variable amount of arguments. In fact the number of arguments reflect - simply speaking - the number of `%`-constructs in the string `formatSpec`. So when you only have one variable that should be formatted and inserted into the output `str`, the command looks very simple (similar to your question):

```
>> A1 = 42;
>> sprintf('demo_%d',A1)
ans =
demo_42
```

Now we can add another variable by adding a new `%`-construct in the format-string and by writing the new variable containing the actual value as another argument `A2`.

```
>> A1 = 42;
>> A2 = 'test';
>> sprintf('demo_%d_%s',A1,A2)
ans =
demo_42_test
```

Note that I used the term *`%`-construct* as simplification for the term *formatting operator*. In the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html#inputarg_formatSpec) you'll find a lot of information on how to use them.

Of course we can add some more variables and format them a bit:

```
>> A1 = 42;
>> A2 = 'test';
>> A3 = 0.012345;
>> A4 = 12;
>> sprintf('demo_%d_%s %.2e %X',A1,A2,A3,A4)
ans =
demo_42_test 1.23e-02 C
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this my simply adding an additional string input to [`sprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html)

```
allData = input('Introduce a variable name:','s');
matfilename = sprintf('xcross_%d_%s.mat', names(k), allData);
```